# Handling different line breaks when comparing a file against a string during tests

Tags: r

I'm having some issues when running tests on Windows using GitHub actions for the package I'm working on. I'm a Mac user and I'm not very familiar with handling strings/files on Windows.

The test consists in creating a temporary file, inserting new lines in that file and comparing it against a character string.

E.g. temporary file:

```
tmp_file <- withr::local_tempfile(
  lines = "foo\nbar",
  fileext = ".txt"
)
```

And the character string to use for comparison:

```
control <- "foo
bar
"
```

The problem is that `readr::read_file(tmp_file)` returns `foo\r\nbar\r\n` on Windows when `control` gives `foo\nbar\n`.

**Q.**: what's the recommended approach to handle that?

Current solutions I can think of include:

- saving the different `control` strings in a file and reading them since `readr::read_file()` will use `\r\n` on Windows.
- creating a function that uses the appropriate linebreak depending on the system. E.g.

```
make_lines <- function(...) {
  sep <- if (.Platform$OS.type == "unix") "\n" else "\r\n"
  out <- paste(..., sep = sep)
  paste0(out, sep)
}
```

The actual test is a bit more complex than that and none of these solutions would be convenient to use here.

Comment: You should look into this on the git(hub) side.  There is a control option that controls line endings and files will come out correct for you on either OS.  That way you will not have to deal with it at all on the Actions side.

Comment: @Dirk Eddelbuettel Thanks. I assume you're talking about core.autocrlf. I set autocrlf using `git config --global core.autocrlf input` in the terminal. My tests keep failing though. I do have `autocrlf = input` in my `.gitconfig` file. On GitHub, one can read `When you set the core.autocrlf option […] you may find that Git reports changes to files that you have not modified`.  I didn't have such change reports, did I miss something?

Comment: IMHO the first comment is well intended but you put github-actions as tag to this r question, and it is actually how the r code behaves on Windows and it is unrelated to `git(1)` and also Microsoft GitHub Actions. I'd suggest to turn this into a standard programming question on SO about the file-handling on windows. E.g. `withr::local_tempfile` has bad symmetry with `readr::read_file`, write the file with a function that uses binary mode as `readr::read_file` does. (text mode converts \n to \r\n on writing and \r\n back to \n on reading). I'd guess there is existing Q&A material on this topic.

Comment: First comments perhaps addresses the `control <- "foo...` lines of code, for a test you could use escape characters: `control <- "foo\r\nbar\r\n"`  - this should give you control with CRLF line terminators (windows standard), on *nix systems all files are binary therefore is should always work, they will use it as well.

Comment: Good points above: it could well be that `readr` "tries to help you" with a windows string when you actually do not want it.  There generally many alternative functions for these things; I had good luck with base R for these things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on @hakre comment, instead of using `readr::read_file()` which reads files with line breaks specific to the operating system, we can make our own function to read lines with the desire line break type on any system.

```r
read_file_test <- function(file) {
  paste(readLines(file), collapse = "\n")
}

read_file_test(tmp_file)
#> foo\nbar
```

Now the output will remain the same on any system so we can easily compare it against a prewritten string.

Alternatively, we can create a `.gitattributes` file and set `eol=lf` so that `read_file()` reads files using `\n`.

For a specific file:

```
path_to_file eol=lf
```

Or for any file:

```
* text=auto eol=lf
```